# Verify Amazon price in asc order-Java Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

Scenario: Search a product in Amazon and then sort by price low to high.
The logic that I thought of is- A) go through each page using while page count... B) save the prices in a list C) verify list[i]< list[i]+1 (current value is less than next value).

Please if you have any better suggestion, kindly mention.

What are the challenges I am having with my code below:
1) Incorrect page count- the actual count should be 5, that's what I see on page but program prints 6
2)Price - the program prints a few prices (I don't know what it is printing). When I try the xpath in the page it moves around so I thought it works.
3) The program ends with an exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <a href="/s?k=yellow+puma+shoes&amp;s=price-asc-rank&amp;lo=visual_grid&amp;page=4&amp;qid=1558648339&amp;ref=sr_pg_3">...</a> is not clickable at point (962, 579). Other element would receive the click: <div class="a-section aok-relative s-image-tall-aspect">...</div>
```

Here is my code:

```
public class AmazonPriceTest {

    public static WebDriver driver;
    //public static List<WebElement> priceAsc;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver= new ChromeDriver();
        //WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
        driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='twotabsearchtextbox']")).sendKeys("yellow puma shoe");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Go']")).click();

        //Implicit wait till page loads
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        //Click on result sort option where we will select price low to high
        Select sortBy=new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='s']")));
        sortBy.selectByValue("price-asc-rank");


        //Scroll down to find pagination
        JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,5000)", "");
        //Number of Pages
        List<WebElement> pagesFound=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='a-pagination']//li//a[contains(@href, '/s?k=yellow+puma+shoes')]"));
        System.out.println("Pages found " + pagesFound.size());

        //Will click on Next link until we reach the last page and keep on saving price in list
        while(pagesFound.size()!=0){
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Next')]")).click();
            List<WebElement> priceAsc=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='a-offscreen']"));
            System.out.println(priceAsc.size());
        }

    }

}
```

If you have few minutes to spare, I could use some help. Thanks in advance for your time. 
Update**: I made the following change and now it keeps on running never stops

```
try{
            while(pagesFound.size() >=0){
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Next')]")).click();
                List<WebElement> priceAsc=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='a-price']//span[@class='a-offscreen']"));
                //System.out.println(priceAsc.size());
                for(int i=0;i<priceAsc.size();i++){
                    System.out.println(priceAsc.get(i).getText());
                }
            }
        }
        catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I would just click the Next if the element is found.  (try/catch it)  If not exit loop.  Pages found will not work by finding pagination count if over a certain amount.  I don't think you need the scroll either.

Comment: Another approach can be:
1. You get the text of the last page[5 in your case], it can be retrieved by below XPath:
(//ul[@class='a-pagination']//li[@class='a-disabled'])[2]
string pageText = driver.findElement(By.Xpath("(//ul[@class='a-pagination']//li[@class='a-disabled'])[2]")).Text
int numOfPages = Convert.ToInt32(pageText)

2. Now create a loop which will iterate till numOfPages(i.e. 5 in your case) minus 1.
for(int i=1; i<numOfPages; i++)
{
 click on "Next" button
}